# Add data in a file, but not out of content? (steganography)

Tags: files, filesystems, encryption

I aim to hide data into *.txt* and *.xml* files, from Linux OS, aand keep it readable on any OS.

> With Apple OS (OS X), I used to write 'secrete' data into files (actually in the Resource Fork of the file), but out of the content of the file. **Example: a file *bob.txt*, when you open it with *Text.app* it displays "hello you", but I placed undisplayed text into *bob.txt* (e.g.: "my_hat_is_redwine"**).

How to "HIDE" textdata with Unix/LinuxTerminal, outside of the content ?

Conditions are:
 - opening the file,
 - zero content alteration.

I have been looking for EOF (end of file), but it does NOT exist on Linux (EOD is an old stuff, very old).

I think about `setfattr`, that's quite ok but I feel sure there is a deeper/stronger way.

**I mean, editing the full file bits chain, and adding bits between content and metada, for instance.**

Comment: That sounds like the "hidden" data was being placed into the resource fork, and thus not visible to anyone who only knows to look at the data fork of the file. I don't ever recall seeing such a forked filesystem on Linux.

Comment: Exactly, isnt there a "start" index for file content in a file, any FS ? Where we could place useless data before (or the inverse: *end-of-content index* and place useless secrete data after) ?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

What you describe on MacOSX is just storing regular data in the *data
fork* of a file, and "secret" data in the *resource fork*.  Major
Linux filesystems provide a more general mechanism, called [extended
attributes](http://linux.die.net/man/5/attr), which can be written
using the [setfattr](http://linux.die.net/man/1/setfattr) command and
read back using [getfattr](http://linux.die.net/man/1/getfattr).

For example::

```
$ echo "Hello, world" > test

$ setfattr -n user.secret -v "Not-easily viewable content goes here" test

$ cat test
Hello, world

$ getfattr -n user.secret test
# file: test
user.secret="Not-easily viewable content goes here"
```

Note that:

- Extended attributes are namespaced; user-defined attributes names must begin with `user.`
- You can store several extended attributes in parallel, e.g., `user.secret1` and `user.secret2`
- Not all filesystems support extended attributes: ext2/3/4, xfs, btrfs do (but they require a mount option which might not be the default on your Linux distro); some other don't (e.g., tmpfs)

Comment: Yes, OSX *Resource fork* system is the thing I used. No matter if Linux FS is diifferent, I aim to hide text data in the file itself, not its content (no stegano')

Comment: This is as close as you are going to get. There is no other "in the file".

Comment: Thank you @RiccardoMurri . Is there a space, that one can create amongst *extended attributes* (metadata) where to write a secret stuff, which remains hidden from metadata editor ?

Comment: @ArchiT3K I'm not sure I understand your last question: how are you going to write the secret stuff into the "metadata" if it's invisible to the utilities to write "metadata" in the first place?

Comment: Riccardo, that's my question... How to write in metadata ?

Comment: @ArchiT3K that's what this answer is about: extended attributes *are* metadata...

Comment: @RiccardoMurri Allright, much thanks. Now (but it s another answer), I wonder how/if-possible to write out of content & metadata file bytes, in a place that is never read, nor displayed, and without breaking the file/integrity.

Comment: @ArchiT3K well, that's an entirely different question -- why don't you ask it separately?